# Is there a way to use GoDaddy's forwarding addresses to send mail on gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, godaddy-api

Hi y'all I have a domain on GoDaddy, I was wondering if I could use their email forwarders as actual emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

If your domain is also registered in Google Domains, you can follow these steps to setup email forwarding:

**Step 1: Set up email forwarding**

1. On your computer, sign in to [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/registrar/)
2. Click on your domain.
3. Open the Menu.
4. Click Email.
5. Under “Email forwarding,” click Add Email Alias.
6. Enter the alias email address and the existing recipient's email address.
7. Click Add.

**Step 2: Activate email forwarding**

Google Domains sends a one-time confirmation email to the recipient email address you entered in Step 1. Follow the instructions in the email to activate email forwarding.

You may not receive a confirmation email and email forwarding begins immediately if:

You’ve previously verified the recipient address with Google Domains for another forwarded email alias. The recipient address is the same address you use to sign in to Google Domains.

**Solution 2:**

Or you can directly go to your DNS host page, in this case, GoDaddy, and add these MX records:

[image]

Please refer to the documentation below for more information:

[Forward your emails](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en)

[Set up email forwarding with custom name servers](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9428703)